# How to concat multiple functions in python

Tags: python, functools

How to do this in python?

```
def f(a, b):
    return a, b+2, b+3
def g(a, b, c):
   return a+b+c
```

How to get something like `k = f+g` hence that

```
k(a, b) is g(f(a,b))
```

Note that this is an abstract question. I wonder whether there's a function that can return a concat of `f+g` or even concat([...]) generally working regardless of the args of `f`.

In another word, I want a function whose args is `f` and `g` and returns `k`:

```
def concat(f,g):
  return something_equivalent_to_k_above
```

Comment: I believe, "compose" would be a proper term for this.

Answer (score 4):

#### Answer for original question

Define:

```
k = lambda x,y:g(*f(x,y))
```

Example:

```
>>> k(2,3)
13
```

#### Answer for revised question

Define:

```
concat = lambda a,b:lambda *args: b(*a(*args))
```

Example:

```
>>> k = concat(f,g)
>>> k(2,3)
13
```

Comment: I revised the question. The question is an "abstract" question. Practically f may have many args. Is there a grace way to do this concat?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 approaches to do this:

Approach A (recommended):

```
def compound(inner_func, outer_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return outer_func(*inner_func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

Note that `inner_func` mustn't return a dictionary, in which case we should write `return outer_func(**inner_func(*args, **argv))`.

Usage:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a, b+2, b+3
def g(a, b, c):
   return a+b+c

k = compound(f, g)

print k(1, 2)
# output: 10
```

---

Approach B:

First, define a "decorator factory" like this:

```
def decorator_factory(inner_func):
    def decorator(outer_func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return outer_func(*inner_func(*args, **kwargs))
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a, b+2, b+3

@decorator_factory(f)
def g(a, b, c):
   return a+b+c

print g(1, 2)
# output: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not define a third function as you did with `f` and `g`:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
        return a, b+2, b+3

>>> def g(a,b,c):
        return a+b+c

>>> def k(a,b):
        return g(*f(a,b))

>>> k(2,3)
13
```